# Getting total count and conditional count in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table called apps in MYSQL database.

| id | source |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fb |
| 2 | gd |
| 3 | tw |
| 4 | fb |
| 5 | qu |
| 6 | fb |

I want a single query that will give me total count along with `fb` count

| totalcount | source |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 |

Comment: "I want..." is rather expectant and greedy in this context; _you_ don't appear to have even attempted to solve _your_ problem. SO is not a "Do this for me" exchange.

Answer (score 7):

To count for `fb` in the table try this: (using `SUM`)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalcount,
SUM(source='fb') source 
FROM table1
```

Another way to do the same: (using `COUNT`)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalcount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'fb' THEN 0 END) source 
FROM table1;
```

To count all source in the table try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) totalcount,
COUNT(DISTINCT source) source 
FROM table1
```

#### [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/706f8e/1)

Comment: SELECT count(*), COUNT(case when source = 'fb' then 0 end) AS FB_COUNT FROM apps ........ WE CAN DO THIS WAY TOO

Comment: @Mdharmendra Yes we can do. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(source='fb') as fb_count, 
       count(*) as totalcount
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff99b/2)